# Static tableview data doesn't appear on device and simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview, uitableview

Anyone can encountered this,

[image]

Set static tableview and label but once I run it, no words appear as in ALL Blank.

It's basic but I can't figure out the reason.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Have you implemented tableview delegate, datasource with individual cell identifier, and make proper linking from your storyboard?

Comment: have you written any code.

Comment: Check in the  Storyboard that corresponding viewcontroller mapped. Is this your rootviewcotroller .What is the output in Device or simulator .

Comment: did you write numberRowsinSection tableview's datasource method

Comment: I am assuming you are using a `UITableViewController`, have you actually set the cells to static in the attributes inspector?

Comment: @NarendraPandey, No written code yet :)

Comment: @Vinodh, Blank without any words of "Invite friends, change password and so on :)

Comment: @KKRocks, Yes I did already.

Comment: @Rikh, Yes I did :)

Comment: Are you setting an data source for the `UITableViewController` programmatically?

Comment: @Rikh, Yes I did :)

Answer (score 0):

you will have to implement `tableview delegate and datasource`

```
[self.tableView setDatasSource:self];
[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
```

you may code it in `viewDidLoad` then implement following datasource.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

also you don't need similar cells again, you can simply reuse one cell using an identifier as follow.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier"];
```

Comment: for static implementation only :)

Comment: yes for static implementation you have to use the UITableView delegates/Datasource i-e return a static `NSInteger` value in `numberOfRowsInSection`.